# помогите сопоставить SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

помогите сопоставить SQL запрос

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE (field_id=1 and value=23) 
  and (field_id=2 and value=3)
```

надо сделать так чтобы проходил по обеим field_id и отсеивал всех с union пробовал он выводит по всем сразу а мне нужно работала по типу and
чтобы проходило так если первый field_id=1 and value=23 то идет дальше и проверяет тех пользователей у которых уже field_id=2 and value=3

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. нужно, чтобы запрос вывел id по второй части условия только если найдены записи для первой части?

Comment: Так кого надо оставить (ну то есть вывести, вернуть, ...)? тех, у кого есть и первая, и  вторая пары? тех, у кого нет ни той, ни другой? тех, у кого есть только одна из двух пар, неважно какая, а второй нет?

Comment: Нужно выводит в тех у кого все варианты совпадают

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь, правильно понял Ваш вопрос.
Используйте EXISTS:

```
select user_id
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data 
WHERE exists (select *
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data where field_id=1 and value=23) 
and (field_id=2 and value=3)
```

вот пример работы запроса - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/939157/2

Comment: Сделал так SELECT user_id FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 474 AND VALUE >'17' ) AND (field_id = 474 AND VALUE <'26') AND (field_id=3 AND value='Marriage') но не заработало

Comment: в условиях задания были другие условия. теперь, естественно, мой запрос не будет работать, т.к. Вы изменили его до неузнаваемости. дайте пример данных и покажите, что именно должен выбрать запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с exists, а можно и с join:

```
SELECT a1.user_id
FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data a1
  JOIN wp_bp_xprofile_data a2 ON a2.user_id=a1.user_id
WHERE a1.field_id=1 and a1.value=23 and
  a2.field_id=2 and a2.value=3
```